# What is the ideal class group?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, ideal-class-group

I'm trying to understand imaginary quadratic fields and the ideal class group seems to be really important, yet I cannot find a simple explanation of it and why it's important. I understand that it is related to unique factorization, yet I don't know why. If someone could give a simple explanation of it and maybe a simple example of it I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I can recommend a new, and inexpensive, book by J. L. Lehman, called Quadratic Number Theory. Does this in expanded, form.

Comment: https://bookstore.ams.org/dol-52/

Comment: The class group of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ has two elements $(1),(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$. Any ideal $I$ of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is of the form $I=(a)$ for some $a \in \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ or $(2a,(1+\sqrt{-5})a)$ for some $a \in (2,1+\sqrt{-5})^{-1} \iff 2a \in (2,1+\sqrt{-5})$. And $(2,1+\sqrt{-5}) = \{ 2b+(1+\sqrt{-5})c, b,c\in \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]\}$.